# Series with gamma functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, gamma-function

I would like to understand how can I write down the expression for the following series:
$$S_0=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^kA^{k}\frac{\Gamma(k-3/2)}{\Gamma(k+1)}.$$
I have seen related topics on this site but I still do not understandt how should I start to find the sum. It is worth mentioning that $A>0$ is the parameter and the series is assumed to be convergent.

Comment: What's $A$ ...?

Comment: @Nosrati , thank you! I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** One may write the expansion of $(1+y)^\alpha$ by Binomial as
$$(1+y)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma(n-\alpha)}{\Gamma(-\alpha)}\dfrac{(-y)^n}{n!}$$
here use $\alpha=\dfrac32$ and $y=A$.

Comment: Thank you! But I would like to emphasize that series starts from $k=2$, does it change something?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Put values into formula and dispart two first terms. Note that the series converges for $|A|<1$.